Problema ao fechar conexões do SQLalchemy
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em python e flask-sqlalchemy e estou tendo problemas com o pool de conexões, as conexões não estão sendo fechadas após as operações no banco de dados, mesmo eu utilizando o gerenciador de contexto with. a configuração do meu projeto esta da seguinte forma:
__init__.py:
   db = SQLAlchemy()
    scheduler = APScheduler()
    
    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)
        CORS(app)
        app.config.from_object(Config)
        
        db.init_app(app)
        scheduler.init_app(app)
        scheduler.start()


run.py:
from app import create_app, db

app = create_app()

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, debug=True)

config.py:
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Carregando dotenv para variáveis de ambiente
load_dotenv()

# Declaração de variáveis de ambiente
APP_ID = os.getenv('APP_ID')
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
REDIRECT_URI_NGROK = os.getenv('REDIRECT_URI_NGROK')

# Variáveis de ambiente para conexão com o banco de dados
hostname = os.getenv('SQL_HOSTNAME')
database = os.getenv('SQL_DATABASE')
username = os.getenv('SQL_USERNAME')
password = os.getenv('password')
password_encoded = quote_plus(password)
domain = "http://127.0.0.1:4000"

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = SECRET_KEY
    print(f"SECRET_KEY:{SECRET_KEY}")
    REDIRECT_URI = REDIRECT_URI_NGROK
    print(f"REDIRECT_URI:{REDIRECT_URI}")
    
    # URI do banco de dados com MySQL e PyMySQL
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password_encoded}@{hostname}/{database}'
    

    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_AUTO_FLUSH = True

    # Configurações para o pool de conexões
    SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
        "pool_size":20,           # Número máximo de conexões no pool
        "max_overflow":1,          # Excesso de conexões além do pool_size
        "pool_timeout":30,         # Tempo máximo para esperar por uma conexão disponível
        "pool_recycle":3600,       # Tempo para reciclar (renovar) conexões
        "pool_pre_ping":True      
    }

    # Configurações do APScheduler
    SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED = True

e por ultimo, um exemplo de uma função que uso para manipular o DB:
def get_total_visits_ontem(self, variacao_selecionada):
        with db.session() as session:
       
            ontem = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
            ontem = ontem.date()  # Obtém apenas a parte da data
            
            total_visits = session.query(func.sum(Acompanhamento_concorrentes.visits_ontem)).filter(
                Acompanhamento_concorrentes.mlb_filho == variacao_selecionada,
                func.date(Acompanhamento_concorrentes.date_checked) == ontem  # Compara apenas a data
            ).scalar()
            
            return total_visits or 0

eu estou importando o db como: from app import db, para utilizar nesse arquivo, mas por algum motivo há conexões ficando em aberto, esgotando o pool de conexões
